# Doctrine recast entity as subclass

Tags: entity-framework, doctrine-orm, single-table-inheritance

I'm updating a system which uses Doctrine2. It has a User class hierarchy which uses single table inheritance. Employee is the base class which is inherited by Department Admin and Company Admin.

I'm trying to provide a way to promote/demote an employee, which would effectively recast the user from Employee to Department Admin or vice versa. Is there a simple way of doing this? Will I have to create a new instance of the role being promoted to and import all the existing entity data into this? Does Doctrine support recasting entities?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer while searching under different key words.

[Doctrine: Update discriminator for SINGLE_TABLE Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610421/doctrine-update-discriminator-for-single-table-inheritance)

It appears you need to import a user's data from one object into another.