# Symfony Multiple Controllers and forms depends of User logged

Tags: forms, symfony, controller, switch-statement, account

I have these controllers

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Products;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UserFormType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;

#[Route('/user')]
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_user_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(UserRepository $userRepository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Products::class);

        return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', [
            'user' => $this->security->getUser(),
            //'admins' => $userRepository->foundAdmins(),
            'products'=>$repository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/new', name: 'app_user_new', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, UserRepository $userRepository,UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher ): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


            $user->setPassword(
                $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('password')->getData()
                )
            );
            $userRepository->save($user, true);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_user_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form,

        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/{id}', name: 'app_user_show', methods: ['GET','POST'])]
    public function show(User $user): Response
    {
        return $this->render('user/show.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/{id}/edit', name: 'app_user_edit', methods: ['GET','POST'])]
    public function edit(Request $request, User $user, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $userRepository->save($user, true);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_user_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/{id}', name: 'app_user_delete', methods: ['GET','POST'])]
    public function delete(Request $request, User $user, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$user->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $userRepository->remove($user, true);
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_user_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }
}
```

AdminController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Products;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UserFormType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;



#[Route('/admin')]
class AdminController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_admin_index')]
    public function index(UserRepository $userRepository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Products::class);
        
        return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig', [
            'users' => $userRepository->findAll(),
            'admins' => $userRepository->foundAdmins(),
            'products'=>$repository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }
    #[Route('/new', name: 'app_admin_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, UserRepository $userRepository,UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher ): Response
    {
        $admin = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $admin);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


            $admin->setPassword(
                $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                    $admin,
                    $form->get('password')->getData()
                )
            );
            $userRepository->save($admin, true);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_admin_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->render('admin/new.html.twig', [
            'user' => $admin,
            'form' => $form,

        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/{id}', name: 'app_admin_show', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function show(User $admin): Response
    {
        return $this->render('admin/show.html.twig', [
            'user' => $admin,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/{id}/edit', name: 'app_admin_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function edit(Request $request, User $admin, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $admin);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $userRepository->save($admin, true);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_user_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->render('admin/edit.html.twig', [
            'user' => $admin,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/{id}', name: 'app_admin_delete', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function delete(Request $request, User $admin, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$admin->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $userRepository->remove($admin, true);
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_admin_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }
}
```

each have two FormType

UserFormType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            //->add('roles',CollectionType::class)->setData("ROLE_USER")
            ->add('password',PasswordType::class)
            ->add('name')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

AdminFormType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class AdminFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('roles',CollectionType::class)
            ->add('password',PasswordType::class)
            ->add('name')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I want to make different forms depends of the account who is logged on. A admin account can define roles (when create a user or another admin) not like users. Actualy the the UserFormType are in use in both forms (new.html.twig, edit.html.twig) dont matter if it's called by AdminController or UserController. Have you an idea or different approach to fix it ? This topic approach of my question but dont exacty respond to it : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060736/symfony-multiple-users-types)

Have tried to find my response on Symfony documentation, at this time i don't have found a response.
Tried to find same issue on forums.

Comment: anonym user can create only (ROLE_USER), admin can create both roles.

Comment: both anonym and logged user can create ROLE_USER to be exact

Comment: I'm a beginner in Symfony Dev

Comment: Issue solved going to add correction

Answer (score 0):

The error thas there (in AdminController.php) :

```
#[Route('/new', name: 'app_admin_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function new(Request $request, UserRepository $userRepository,UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher ): Response
{
    $admin = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(AdminFormType::class, $admin);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


        $admin->setPassword(
            $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                $admin,
                $form->get('password')->getData()
            )
        );
        $userRepository->save($admin, true);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_admin_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }
```

I've forgot to change `UserFormType::class` in `createform()` function replaced by AdminFormType. Add also use App\Form\AdminFormType; in dependencies.