# Symfony5 How to create multiple types of users with different login forms

Tags: php, symfony

I started learning Symfony and already know how to create a user and registration / login forms for him using `php bin/console make:user` `php bin/console make:auth`, but I need to have several types of users like `Client`, `Company`, `Admin` and what if I try go to `example.com/company`, we were thrown to the login window for the Company account (I’m now thrown to the login form for the User).

After searching I found these questions [Symfony / Doctrine - Multiple Users Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53286674/symfony-doctrine-multiple-users-types/53296163) and [Symfony: Firewalls, multiple login forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366637/symfony-firewalls-multiple-login-forms), but I did not understand what to do next and how to combine them. Please tell me.

Comment: Hi Didra and welcom on SO, plesae have a look to this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. We will be happy to answer if you provide a prescise question including coding examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think better solution for You will be using roles to determine them ;)

You can have one entity and make some getters like:

```
public function isAdmin():bool
{
    return in_array(self::ROLE_ADMIN, $this->roles, true);
}
```

And if you want split roles to different path prefixes you can have one firewall eg: app that matches all your application and next make correct access_controll rules like this:

```
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/company, roles: ROLE_CLIENT }
```

And are You sure company is another user class or permission? Maybe better assign admin to company and allow them to access this companies? ;)

If you realy want to split them you could use doctrine discriminator, eg. create Abstract user and next 3 classes extending them, you can configure security using that abstract class.

Or create 3 providers, 3 firewalls, and same access_controll like above